# Spring MVC - how to pass model attribute to multiple JSP's

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

This might be very basic question, but I'm really struggling to find anything that could solve this issue. So, my question is, how to pass single model attribute to multiple JSP's. Is this even possible? Basically, I have a web application which dinamicaly creates menu upon login. That's why I need to pass one attribute to multiple JSP's. Or even better, can this be solved by passing attribute to tag?

Comment: No, JSPs work on request attributes. Add your object to the model, it will end up in the request attributes. All JSPs rendered with that `HttpServletRequest` will have access to it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Doh! I totally forgot about that. Can you make that as an answer? Since it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPs are processed and can access `HttpServletRequest` attributes. All you need to do is get your objects in there. To do so, add your objects to the `Model`. Spring will transfer them from the `Model` into the `HttpServletRequest` and you will then have access to them in any JSP processed during that request.